# Trying to create reusable "widgets/forms" within an MVC application, View and possibly Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3, C#, Razor, EF4.1.

I am exploring the best approach to creating a reusable form across many Views. Its functionality would thus contain the Form bit(View) and the Database saving bit(Controller).

My current  idea is:

```
Use a Partial View that can be used by many views to contain the reusable form.
```

Then

```
Use an extra Action("Add Item") in the Controller for the master View which calls a method off a reusable class ie GenericDataItem.Save(strData);
```

Another idea I had was to have a generic Controller to match the partial View. So the form in the Partial View only calls the generic Controller which then has to hand control back to the master controller via RedirectToAction or equivalent. Obviously this latter approach means that the "Widget" controller code is only written once.

Your wisdom and recommendations would be appreciated on this important issue. A good strategy can obviously help a greatly simplified approach to MVC construction.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The two approachs have benefits. I will use as an example, a project that I used to work on (I joined latter in the project and wasn't involved in modeling):

In this project, an user could be allocated in differents groups at the same time, and his starting page in each section of the site was different, varying with the authorizations he had in each group. In this (very especific) situation, we used the approach you suggested first, manily because an user could not have (for example), the authorization to access the PartialViewA when accessing the page of Section X, but could have tha authorization to access the PartialViewA when acessing the page of Section A.

But, again, this is a very specific situation and I'm pretty sure this isn't your case. I just decide to write it here to show a situation where each case would become useful.

Your second approach is the one I suggest, because, as you said, this approach means that the "Widget" controller code is only written once. I use it in the projects I'm working at this time.